# open all contacts on button click in ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to open Apple's inbuilt contact book on button click.
I have tried some other codes, but it didn't work.
I have added 4 libraries in my project.

Comment: Check this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-import-contact-address-book/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code to open default contact list and manage this list by its delegate methods:

```
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    picker.predicateForEnablingPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.@count > 0", ABPersonPhoneNumbersProperty];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And don't forget to import addressbook frameworks and its delegates in you view controller.

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

Delegate :

```
 ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access address book using:

First import`#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>`

```
 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

# pragma mark - peoplePickerDelegate methods
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
   - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
[self displayPerson:person];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
return NO;
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                            property:(ABPropertyID)property
                          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
return NO;
}
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,                                                               kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSString* phone = nil;
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                 kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
} else {
    phone = @"[None]";
}
CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
}
```

It may help you...